# Bitshifting to multiply an integer by 10

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Simple question, but I can't quite seem to figure it out:

If i have an integer, say 12, and I perform the following bit-manipulation on it:

```
int i = 12;  
i = (i << 3) + (i << 1);
```

I end up with 120 (12*10). This is the case with any number.

Can someone explain to me, succinctly, why it is that this works? (I'm obviously missing something quite rudimentary when it comes to bitshifting).

Comment: Do you know how bitshifting works? `i << 3` is i*(2^3) or i*8, and `i << 1` is i*(2^1) or i*2, so if you add those, you get i*10.

Comment: He're you go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Shift_and_add

Comment: Also note that any *decent* compiler will do this better than you... Just use plain multiplication and the optimizer will do what's best for you in the current platform.

Comment: In agreement with David's comment: *Please do not do this when you want to multiply*.  You can also divide by powers of 2 using `>>` operations, and in some cases substitute `&` for `%`.  But that's not what bitwise operators are for.

Comment: There is a good situation for doing these shift-based multiplies: ancient hardware. The 6502 (C64, NES, Atari, Apple II) has no multiply instruction, so the fastest way to multiply by ten is to add the results of two left shifts by 3 and 1 together. Ancient CPUs that have multiply instructions didn't multiply fast either, so often something like this would outrun a multiply instruction.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Express as multiplication.

```
i = (i << 3) + (i << 1);
i = (i * 8) + (i * 2);
i = 8i + 2i
i = 10i
```

Comment: is it really faster than multiplying by 10?

Answer (score 6):

You are basically doing:

```
i = i*2^3 + i*2
```

Answer (score 5):

`i << 3` is equivalent to `i * 8`. `i << 1` is equivalent to `i * 2`.

The [distribute property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) tells us that:

```
x = i * 10
x = i * (8 + 2)
x = 8i + 2i
```

Answer (score 1):

Shifting left by 3 places is equal to multiplying by 8, shifting by 1 places is equal to multiplying by 2 so you are doing

```
i = i * 8 + i * 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Left bitshift is the same (usually) as multiplying by power's of two. i.e. `<< 1` is equivalent to `*(2^1)` , `<< 2` is equivalent to `*(2^2)` and so on...

If you substitute that into your example you can see why your result is multiplied by 10:

```
int i = 12;
i = (i * 2^3) + (i * 2^1);
= { i = (i * 8) + (i * 2);}
= { i = 8i + 2i; }
= { i = 10i; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the bitshifts as multiplications by powers-of-2, and all should become clear.